# Adding an icon and logo to header in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, header

I would like to add 2 icons, one to the right the other to the left, and in between I would like to add a logo. It won't let me add it to the header for some reason. Please help!

Comment: post your code...

Comment: Do you mean you need icon in your title bar?

Comment: Yes, so I want to put my logo in the middle of the title bar so that people see the name of the app. And even when they scroll down the logo stays in the title bar. Do I have to create a theme for that or how would that work?